# Fragments and Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I am using the navigation drawer in Android Studio. When I select an item in navigation drawer I'm using the following code:

```
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
    switch(position)
        {
            case 0:
                Intent intent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this,HomeActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent1);
                break;
            case 1:
                Intent intent2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this,DayActivity_1.class);
                startActivity(intent2);
                break;
        }
}
```

When I call my activities from the navigation drawer item selected the action bar disappears and activities open on full screen. How can I manage that the navigation drawer doesn't disappear?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to persist navigation drawer you should change content fragment, instead of showing Activity.

In your case it would be, change

```
Intent intent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this,HomeActivity.class); startActivity(intent1);
```

with:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = ...
FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.your_fragment_container_id, new HomeFragment())
transaction.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

dont use DayActivity_1.class activity use fragment instead and when you click on navigation item jst create fragment and replace it to the drawerlayout

Answer (score 0):

Extend FragmentActivity in you main navigation activity class like below.

```
public class NavigationdrawerActivity extends FragmentActivity
```

Now use the below code to solve your problem

```
public void setContent(Fragment fragment) {
        // Fragment fragment = new content_home();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentManager = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentManager.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.enter_from_left, R.animator.exit_to_left);
       // fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        fragmentManager.replace(R.id.mainContent, fragment).commit();

    }

public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
    switch(position)
        {
            case 0:

                break;
            case 1:
                Intent intent2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this,DayActivity_1.class);
                startActivity(intent2);
                break;
        }
}

public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
    switch(position)
        {
            case 0:
                 Fragment homeActivityFragment = new HomeActivityFragment();
                 //if you want to pass data to fragment
                  //Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                  //bundle.putString("id", "" + item.get("id"));
                  //homeActivityFragment.setArguments(bundle);
                 setContent(homeActivityFragment)
                break;
            case 1:
                Fragment dayActivity_1Fragment = new DayActivity_1Fragment();
                setContent(dayActivity_1Fragment)
                break;
        }
}
```